# Pitch Shift with DirectSound

Tags: c#, windows, audio, directsound, pitch-shifting

How to do pitchshifting with DirectSound in C#? I didn't find anything useful in Google. SetFrequency isn't good for me, beacuse this changes also the speed of the sound. I don't want to create a wav file for each pitch, beacuse that would result in a very big software.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_timescale-pitch_modification) for getting an overview about timescale-pitch modifications of audio material.

And look at this [similar so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091198/pcm-data-pitch-change-in-c) for more info.

And [here](https://sites.google.com/site/mikescoderama/pitch-shifting) i found an implementation of the *Short-Time Fourier Transform* pitch shifter algorithm in C#.